# How to do a dynamic ps.setString() in Java

Tags: java, sql

I have a problem with my code. I do not know how to properly insert these sample records in the database. It runs, but the output in the database is wrong. It displays the same value each column and iterate every row.

Here is my code:

```
String[] arr = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "010"};
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
String sql = "INSERT INTO insertTable(POSTAL_CODE_NO_,VERTEX_CODES,STATE,COUNTY,CITY) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int index = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            pst.setString(index, arr[i]);
            index++;
        }

        pst.addBatch();
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
}
```

Comment: There is not enough code to understand your problem. With the peace you shared  my guess is that you need to execute your database command within the FOR statement you add the parameter.

Comment: I don't see the point of the inner `for` loop in `j`.  You never use that dummy loop counter.  Please show us the SQL query you are trying to execute.

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO insertTable(POSTAL_CODE_NO_,VERTEX_CODES,STATE,COUNTY,CITY) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";

Comment: There are 5 columns that i need to populate with records.

Comment: *"It displays the same value each column"* Of course it does, because you're setting the same value for all 5 columns.

Comment: You say the *"output in the database is wrong"*, but you get exactly what you coded. What did you expect it to do. Perhaps you should read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) articles "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". The *Verifiable* parts means: *"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the **expected behavior** should be".*

Comment: I wanted the output to be Col1 = 1, col2=2, col3=3, col4=4, col5=5...not col1=1, col2=1, col3=3 and so on

Comment: @JohnRanelTuble But you have 10 values in the input, and only 5 columns??? Or did you mean that you wanted 2 rows created, first row with `1,2,3,4,5` and second row with `6,7,8,9,010`? If so, **edit** the question and say that, to clarify your *expectation*.

Answer (score 0):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699766/how-to-do-a-dynamic-ps-setstring-in-java/51699960#comment90361541_51699766) to question:

> I wanted the output to be Col1 = 1, col2=2, col3=3, col4=4, col5=5...not col1=1, col2=1, col3=3 and so on

To do that, you need the array index variable to increase every time the column index increases. The code below has been changed to do that.

The code has also been changed to use try-with-resources for correct resource management.

The code will of course fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the length of `arr` is not an exact multiple of the number of columns. In this case it is, creating 2 rows.

```
String[] arr = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "010"};

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO insertTable" +
                " ( POSTAL_CODE_NO_, VERTEX_CODES, STATE, COUNTY, CITY )" +
                " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= 5; col++, i++) {
                pst.setString(col, arr[i]);
            }
            pst.addBatch();
        }
        pst.executeBatch();
    }
}
```

Notice how `i++` has been moved to second `for` loop.

Answer (score -2):

If you are planning to pass the values dynamically you can use '?' where you need to set the parameter.

For example select * from Employee where emp_id=? '?' can be replaced by any value in run time.

In your scenario Insert into table table_name col1,col2,col3 values (?,?,?)

Comment: OP *is* using `?`, otherwise `pst.setString` would have failed. --- And now that actual SQL is added to question, it's even more clear.